# How to show computed property values in EPiServer 8?

Tags: episerver

In page edit mode I want to show a read-only text that is based on a page property value. The text could for example be "A content review reminder email will be sent 2015-10-10", where the date is based on the page published date + six months (a value that will be configurable and therefore can change anytime). So far I've tried to accomplish something like this by adding another property on the page.

I've added the property *CurrentReviewReminderDate* to an *InformationPage* class we use. In page edit mode the property name is shown, but it doesn't have a value. How do I do to show the value in page edit mode (preferably as a label)?

```
[CultureSpecific]
[Display(
    Name = "Review reminder date",
    Description = "On this date a reminder will be sent to the selected mail to remember to verify page content",
    Order = 110)]
[Editable(false)]
public virtual string CurrentReviewReminderDate
{
    get
    {
        var daysUntilFirstLevelReminder =
            int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PageReviewReminder_DaysUntilFirstLevelReminder"]);
        if (CheckPublishedStatus(PagePublishedStatus.Published))
        {
            return StartPublish.AddDays(daysUntilFirstLevelReminder).ToString();
        }
        return "";
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetPropertyValue(p => p.CurrentReviewReminderDate, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you exposing the PageData object directly in your views or do you transfer the `currentPage` object to a ViewModel?

Comment: Does it matter? The property is not shown to visitors, only to the web editors in page edit mode.

Comment: I don't like to criticize without knowing the demand spec but that logic will never work, seems as if you need to take it back to the drawing board. If you are to work with retention of review policies I'd recommend you to build a timer job instead. Feel free to contact me on twitter @ericherlitz and we can discuss what you are trying to accomplish!

Comment: @Eric: It is combined with a scheduled job. But this property is supposed to inform the page editor when a reminder will be sent.

Comment: In that case, why aren't the `CurrentReviewReminderDate` a DateTime object and why are you trying to fake a date? Seems to me as if `CurrentReviewReminderDate` should be a regular auto property that you update from that scheduled job ensuring it to be stored with the pagedata object. If you want to automatically update the `CurrentReviewReminderDate` property during publish you should use event handling.

Comment: Well, the scheduled job checks which pages is out of date and sends a reminder by mail to the responsible web editor, it does not try to update the property value. I don't want to update the property value when the page is being published, the delay in days before sending a reminder is read from config and can change anytime, if the value changes it means that all saved values would be wrong.

Comment: I don't want the value to be editable by the web editors, so I tried to make it look like a label as much as possible, and I thought a textbox (for string) was more like it than a datepicker (for DateTime). It really doesn't matter, it's not used in any other way than informing the web editors when a page review reminder for the page is about to be sent.

Comment: Will it be sufficient if it is visible in the DOPE editor as a label and hidden in the forms edit mode?

Comment: No, but it would be sufficient if it's visible in forms edit mode only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to hook into the **LoadedPage**-event and add the value from there. This might not be the best way performance-wise since you need to do a CreateWritableClone, but depending on the site it might not matter.

```
    [InitializableModule]
[ModuleDependency(typeof(EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule))]
public class EventInitialization : IInitializableModule
{
    public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
    {
        ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentEvents>().LoadedContent += eventRegistry_LoadedContent;
    }

    void eventRegistry_LoadedContent(object sender, ContentEventArgs e)
    {
        var p = e.Content as EventPage;
        if (p != null)
        {
            p = p.CreateWritableClone() as EventPage;
            p.EventDate = p.StartPublish.AddDays(10);
            e.Content = p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that way the property value is shown in edit mode! But is it really good to alter the writable status of a page in this place? Isn't it writeprotected for a good reason?

Comment: The original cached instance is read-only for performance. Notice however, that if you do this, your property would actually save the value. Given how your property getter is implemented, however, it probably wouldn't matter. I hate sounding negative, but this whole approach seems like a bit of an anti-pattern - and potentially confusing to other developers. :)

Comment: Personally I would probably try to find another solution, but if it's a tight deadline and low budget, then I would probably go for a quick easy solution like this. As Ted says the value will be saved, but you could always clear it before saving with another event hookup. Don't know what the perk would be though. :)

Comment: Well, so far I haven't seen any other solution on how to set a page property value based on the value of another page property. So, I'll try this out and hope the performance won't take a too big hit.

Answer (score 2):

EPiServer internally uses the **GetPropertyValue** method (i.e. the opposite of **SetPropertyValue**) when retrieving content for the UI.

This makes sense, otherwise your "made-up" value would be stored as the real value whenever the content is saved. *This would make fall-back values etc impossible to implement*.

So, this is by-design (and quite wisely so) in EPiServer. :)

However, you can customize how properties work by:

1. Using custom editors by applying UI hints
2. Modifying property metadata (for example, to display a generated value as a watermark in a textbox without interfering with the actual value being saved)

I could be misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but off the top of my head it looks like a custom editor could be a viable option for your use case?

Comment: You seem to understand my problem all right. I'll try your suggestions  (and accept your answer if I get it to work :)  )

Comment: Good luck! This might help you get started: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-CMS/7/Editing/How-To/Registering-a-Custom-Editor/

Comment: If I try to solve this problem using a custom editor, I don't see how I in the custom editor code would be able to a) get the value of another property on the page b) edit the property value of the property that is rendered with the custom editor

Comment: Custom editors require some knowledge of Dojo. But maybe you should consider outputting something in the page view instead? I.e., if the page is in editing mode, you display some sort of notification on the page?

Comment: That sounds interesting, do you have a starting point for me there?

Comment: You can check PageIsInEditMode in your view and simply display some additional HTML: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7/1063a7dc-47a6-cd10-7fa4-ccd422050fa6

Comment: Nevermind, saw the other comment about it not being enough to display it in on-page edit mode. However, I would still recommend doing that, unless you create a custom editor (or other UI component) using Dojo. If you decide to create a custom editor, you could have a look at this: http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Linus-Ekstrom/Dates/2012/7/Creating-a-custom-editor-for-a-property/

Comment: Displaying it in DOPE-mode seems do-able, but I think DOPE-mode is supposed to show the page in a preview mode and it feels wrong to show info there that won't be visible to page visitors. And I got two other properties that are related to this property, so I'd like to have them grouped and I don't want them visible in DOPE-mode.